# Page shows all Semantic UI modals when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, ejs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to have a popup for the description of a book when a user clicks the "view details" button, and I am trying to accomplish that using the semantic ui modal. Because I have several books to render, I am using an ejs loop to loop through all the data at once, but every time I click on the button, all of the modals show up, instead of just the one book description.

Here is my ejs code

```
<% include header.ejs %>
<% include nav.ejs %>
<div class="page-hero" style="background-image: url('a.jpg'); width: 100%;">
<h1 id="eachTitle">ADD BOOK</h1>
</div>
<div class="ui container">
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." required class="searchBook">
    <input type="submit" class="ui button basic blue"value="Search">
</form>
<iframe name="target" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<% for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){ %>
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="column four wide">
            <form method="POST" action="">
            <div class="ui card">
                <div class="image">
                    <input value="<%= results[i].thumbnail %>" name="image" style="display: none">
                    <img src = "<%= results[i].thumbnail %>"/>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="header">
                        <input class="ui small header title" value="<%= results[i].title %>" readonly name="title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="meta">
                        <div class="des">Author:<input class="desc" value="<%= results[i].authors %>" readonly name="author"></div><br>
                        <div class="des">Published on:<input class="desc" value="<%= results[i].publishedDate %>" readonly name="date"></div><br>
                        <div class="des">Pages:<input class="desc" value="<%= results[i].pageCount %>" readonly name="pages"></div><br>
                        <div class="des">Rating:<input class="desc" value="<%= results[i].averageRating %>" readonly name="rating" style="display: none">
                            <div class="star-ratings-css">
                                <div class="star-ratings-css-top" style="width: <%= results[i].averageRating * 26.5 + "%" %>"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
                                <div class="star-ratings-css-bottom"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="modaldiv" class="ui modal" style="position: relative">
                        <i class="close icon"></i>
                        <div class="header"><%=results[i].title%></div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <input value="<%= results[i].description%>" readonly style="display: none" name=description>
                            <%= results[i].description%>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Should be out side of the book info div -->
                <div class="content extra">
                    <a class="ui button basic fluid detail">View Detail</a>
                    <button class="add ui button basic fluid" type="submit" name="button" id="<%= results[i].title %>">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
<% } %>
</div>
<% include footer.ejs%>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('click', ".detail", function(){
          $(".ui.modal").modal("show");
      })
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know a way that I can stop this from happening?

Comment: Well, you have on document click. Which modal should be displayed in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with the name of the modal in your loop. It's all time the same so when you call it here :

> $(".ui.modal").modal("show");

All your modals have the same name, so all the modal just show themselves.

Give their an unique name, and call the unique name.

For exemple :

```
<div class="ui modal"+<% loop.index %> style="position: relative">
```

And you can call it :

```
$(".ui.modal.(loop.index)").modal("show");
```

On this way, you will call only one of your modal, just play with the classname or the id.